# Using multiple foreignkeys returns sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

*Probably a duplicate, but nothing worked.*
*If a duplicate, please link it*

I'm trying to do an one-to-many relation (`Route` can be used by many `index_GridCell`), but every solution i found still raises an exception:
`sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Route.igc - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the  'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

I tried everything i could find, but o got back to square zero. I only know that the problem comes for using more than one foreign key.

I have the current `models.py`:

```py
import pickle
from app import db

class Route(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128))

    total_accesses = db.Column(db.Integer)
    last_access = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    igc = db.relationship('index_GridCell', backref = 'route')

    def query_by_id(id) -> list:
        return Route.query.filter_by(id = id).all()


class index_GridCell(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    route_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('route.id')) #just for management
    route_url = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('route.url'))

    title = db.Column(db.String(128))
    description = db.Column(db.String(128))
    tags = db.Column(db.PickleType)
```

And i use this to create they:

```py
rt = Route(url = '/', total_accesses = 0, last_access = 0)
i_gc = index_GridCell(title = 'test_title', description = 'test_desc', tags = ['test', 'tags'], route = rt)
        
db.session.add(rt)
db.session.add(i_gc)
db.session.commit()
```

**Versions:**
Python                    3.7.2
SQLAlchemy                1.3.23
Flask-SQLAlchemy          2.4.4
Flask                     1.1.2

Comment: Foreign keys are a reference to the primary key of another table, which defines a uniqueness. The referenced data record or the object can be loaded using this foreign key. You should remove the foreign key which refers to "route.url" within "index_GridCell". To make your example work, it only needs the foreign key on the primary key "index.id". Take a look at [these](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) examples.

Comment: So to get the url, instead of using foreign keys, is use `route_id` and do an search by the corresponding `Route` in the database? I was trying to avoid this due to optimization, but i'm not sure

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.
A route has several IndexGridCells and an IndexGridCell belongs to exactly one route. It's easier to imagine the tables. The relationship arises depending on the table in which the foreign key is saved. 
Do you want to get all routes to a url?
Do you want to query the associated url of the referenced route of an IndexGridCell? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: A Route can have many indexGridCell, but a indexGridCell need to belong to exactly one Route. Yes, when i query an indexGridCell, i want the url from the associated Route, without making another query using the route_id. You Said basically all what i need...

Comment: You can of course define the url as a foreign key. However, this means that it is defined as a primary key within the routes table and is therefore unique. So you could do without a column id. It's a little quirky and adds to the storage requirements of your database. As an alternative, you can load the relationship in one go if you use an SQL JOIN statement. You can do this by setting [```lazy='joined'```](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html) within the relationship. However, it is also possible to formulate your own query using join.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and did a work around:

**Models.py:**

```py
class Route(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'route'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key = True)

    total_accesses = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    last_access = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)

    def query_by_id(id) -> list:
        return Route.query.filter_by(id = id).all()
    
    def get_last_id() -> int:
        qr = Route.query.order_by(Route.id.desc()).first()
        return qr.id if qr else 0


class index_GridCell(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'i_gc'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)

    route_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('route.id'), nullable = False)
    route_url = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('route.url'), nullable = False)

    route = db.relationship('Route', foreign_keys = [route_id])
    route1 = db.relationship('Route', foreign_keys = [route_url])

    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    tags = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable = False)
```

**app.py:** *to create the db entry*

```py
form_url = request.form['url']
form_title = request.form['title']
form_description = request.form['description']
form_tags = ''.join(request.form['tags'].split()).split(',')

rt = Route(id = Route.get_last_id() + 1, url = form_url, total_accesses = 0, last_access = dt.datetime.now())
i_gc = index_GridCell(title = form_title, description = form_description, tags = form_tags,
            route = rt,
            route1 = rt)
        
db.session.add(rt)
db.session.add(i_gc)
db.session.commit()
```

I removed the relationship from the `Route` side, and did one for each foreign key i needed, then when create an new `index_GridCell`, i specify `route=rt, route1=rt`.
If i need another foreign key, i will specify `route2=rt`, create a new relationship `route2 = db.relationship('Route', foreign_keys = [<my_foreign_key>])`
As autoincrement don't work with SQLite and composite primary keys, *whatever does this mean*, i needed to autoincrement `Route.id` by myself, if didn't, he will be null and raise an exception.

This is probably one of the worst ways of resolving this, but i couldn't find any solution, and is a **personal project**, i don't really need fancy things.